# In my Express Routes When I use '/' end point in my router, it works, however when I change the endpoint to '/login' it doesn't work

Tags: express

I have a simple express app with below index.js route file under routes folder

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Express!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Require the routes file
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');

// Use the routes as middleware
app.use('/', indexRoutes);

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Above code work if I hit get request from postman on "http://localhost:3000"

However if I add endpoint'/login' in index.js file as below

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Express!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Respectively I update the app.js file, and hit Get Request from postman on url "http://localhost:3000/login"

updated app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Require the routes file
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');

// Use the routes as middleware
app.use('/login', indexRoutes);

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Can someone give me more insight on what is wrong in my code?

After adding '/login' route I should get "Hello, Express!" in my postman response, however I am getting below response, If I remove login text from the endpoint from index.js and my app.js it works

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /login</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the `/login` route twice, once in your `app.js` file, and again in your `routes/index.js` file. So the endpoint that will return the `"Hello, Express!"` response will actually be `http://localhost:3000/login/login`.

To get the response you want at `http://localhost:3000/login`, you can remove the `login` from either file. So in `app.js`, it can be `app.use('/login', indexRoutes);`, in which case, in `routes/index.js` it will be

```js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Express!');
});
```

Or in `app.js`, it can be `app.use('/', indexRoutes);`, in which case, in `routes/index.js` it will be

```js
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Express!');
});
```